Different Pythons, PyCharm cannot correctly detect installed versions
Different Python installations.
Anaconda :

(base) C:\\Users\\locks\>python --version, gives Python 3.11.7.  Win 11
C:\\Users\\locks\>python --version gives Python 3.12.3...

How do I solve this problem? Anaconda was installed first. Much later, PyCharm was installed which prompted for a Python installation. At the Anaconda Prompt, I tried
(base) C:\\Users\\locks\>conda update --all that did not fix the issue.
Started to investigate when
from sympy import \* 
was executed OK in Jupyter notebook but failed in PyCharm. If I changed the Python Interpreter in PyCharm from 312 to 311 it worked OK.
What is the best way to straighten everything out properly?
Many thanks in advance.
Locksley
I tried -
(base) C:\\Users\\locks\>conda update --all.
I thought that would move Anaconda to Python 3.12.

It seems you have 2 python installations. Try uninstalling python via Control Panel and leave only Anaconda. Than select conda installation in PyCharm interpreter settings.

Jupyter and PyCharm, do not necessarily use the same Python kernels.  If you want Python 3.12 or a specific python kernel in PyCharm you can visit
Settings>Project Interpreter and change/add new interpreter from the right part of the window. An example is shown to you below.
This should generally work for Jupyter, although the Jupyter settings in PyCharm might be a bit different.


Thanks for your response. Python 3.11 was installed when Anaconda was installed. When I use  Python 3.12 interpreter , lots of packages are missing including simpy, which started my investigation. If I use Python 3.11 interpreter, all works OK. I will continue using 3.11 for now. Thanks much.

Well unless you give conda update python, when you install a new python enviroment or let's say python version with anaconda, you have to reinstall the packages you need to use in the new environment. This is perhaps what you are missing so far. Hovever, if 3.11 works for you that's still fine.
